# Give user SFTP access to specific folder only - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, ubuntu-14.04

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04 and need to give a user access to the web root of a site hosted there.

The site is at var/www/projectname/public_html (e.g. outside of the user's home directory).

How do I securely grant them an SFTP login to that folder only while also denying ssh access? Thanks!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict access to a specific directory you can use the `ChrootDirectory` directive. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory) question for more information.

Your second question (allowing SFTP but disabling SSH access) has been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh).

Answer (score 1):

**Limit the Access to the User**

Here, we will only allow the user to perform file transfer and we will disable the terminal access.

For that add the following codes at the bottom of the configuration file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Now the file will open and paste the code.

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

. . .

Match User filemg

ForceCommand internal-sftp

PasswordAuthentication yes

ChrootDirectory /var/sftp

PermitTunnel no

AllowAgentForwarding no

AllowTcpForwarding no

X11Forwarding no
```

Replace `filemg` with your user name. Then save and close the file.

That's it.

Reference: [How to use SFTP in Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.techlinu.com/use-sftp-ubuntu-16-04/)